# CRM 2011: Retrive multiple from QueryExpression have data on Entity return but GetAttributeValue always blank

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, workflow

I'm using Query Expression to retrieve related records through N:N relationship between 2 entities (User and Engagement)

But when I proceed with return data from query. the method entity.Attributes["systemuserid"] always return blank although it has data.

Here is my code:

```
 QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression(CrmAttributes.EntityName.User);
            query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(CrmAttributes.SystemUserAttributes.UserId);
            LinkEntity linkEntityFrom = new LinkEntity(CrmAttributes.EntityName.User,
                CrmAttributes.EntityRelationships.EngagementToSystemUser,
                CrmAttributes.SystemUserAttributes.UserId, CrmAttributes.SystemUserAttributes.UserId,
                JoinOperator.Inner);
            LinkEntity linkEntityTo = new LinkEntity(CrmAttributes.EntityRelationships.EngagementToSystemUser,
                CrmAttributes.EntityName.Engagement,
                CrmAttributes.EngagementAttributes.EngagementId, CrmAttributes.EngagementAttributes.EngagementId,
                JoinOperator.Inner);
            linkEntityFrom.LinkEntities.Add(linkEntityTo);
            query.LinkEntities.Add(linkEntityFrom);
            linkEntityFrom.LinkCriteria = new FilterExpression();
            linkEntityFrom.LinkCriteria.AddCondition(
                new ConditionExpression(CrmAttributes.EngagementAttributes.EngagementId, ConditionOperator.Equal, id));
            var results = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);


 foreach (var entity in results.Entities)
      { 
            if(entity.Attributes.Contains(CrmAttributes.SystemUserAttributes.UserId)) {
                Guid userGuid = entity.Attributes[CrmAttributes.SystemUserAttributes.UserId]  //systemuserid
                tracer.Trace("Guid: " + userGuid);      // Always blank 
           }
       }
```

But when I use KeyValuePair to get data. The data is exactly what I want

```
 foreach (var entity in results.Entities)
                { 
                    Guid userGuid = new Guid();
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> attribute in entity.Attributes)
                    {
                        if (attribute.Key == CrmAttributes.SystemUserAttributes.UserId)
                        {
                            userGuid = (Guid)attribute.Value;
                            tracer.Trace("Guid: " + userGuid); //Return expected data
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: How does it even compile with this line -> `Guid userGuid = entity.Attributes[CrmAttributes.SystemUserAttributes.UserId];`?

Comment: It's defined in the other class.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain `systemuserid` is the correct field name to use for this query?

When joins are involved, CRM will often use a different attribute name as many entities could have fields with the same name.

For example it could be something like `user1.systemuserid`.

I would suggest debugging the code to review the attributes returned by the query - I suspect you will find the information you require.

Comment: Yes, It is. Everything in the code have written exactly what I learned from Microsoft document.

Answer (score 0):

After a day leave this problem alone. It run perfectly now without any modification was made... Maybe something went wrong on the SDK or my CRM server and it took me a day to workaround with no answer @@.